# Understanding space complexity - BFS solution - Painting a boolean matrix

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search, space-complexity

I am trying to understand the space complexity of a BFS solution for the painting a boolean matrix problem in "Elements of Programming Interview". It is similar to Flood fill problem (Problem 733) in Leetcode.

The solution goes like this. I can add the current element that needs the change to the queue. Any adjacent (Top/Bottom/Up/Down) nodes need a change as well. So I add them to the queue (If they satisfy the criteria to be added to the queue. Whenever an element from the queue is processed, its adjacent elements are added. We will do the processing till queue is not empty.

I was thinking the space complexity (worst case) will be O(MN) because all the elements could be in the queue as well. But the book mentions that the worst case space complexity is O(M+N) since there are at most O(M+N) entries at a given distance from a node. I understand that elements are constantly getting removed from the queue as well. Even then it is hard for me to imagine how they arrive at this space complexity. Can someone please help me understand?

Comment: Now that we proved it wrong (see kaya3's updated answer) I'm wondering whether the book is actually wrong or whether its problem is "similar" but not really equivalent and maybe has more constraints so that O(M+N) is actually correct in their case. Can you check again and maybe tell some more what the book says?

Comment: @HeapOverflow You are correct. The leetcode problem you tagged is the similar one. I still don't know why it is marked as O(m+n) in the book. Reasoning given is that there are at most m+n vertices that are at same distance from a given entry.

Answer (score 3):

The key to this is that BFS visits nodes in order of their distance from the starting node. This is what makes BFS suitable for finding [shortest paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Unweighted_graphs) in unweighted graphs.

At any point in time, the queue cannot contain two nodes `u` and `v` such that `distance(start, u)` and `distance(start, v)` differ by more than 1. Suppose for the sake of argument that `u`'s distance from the starting node is 3, and `v`'s distance is 5:

- If `v` occurs before `u` in the queue, then we visit it before `u` - a contradiction, because BFS visits nodes at earlier distances before nodes at greater distances.
- If `u` occurs before `v` in the queue, then when we visit `u`, we will add `u`'s neighbours to the queue. Those neighbours are at distance 4 from the starting node, but they are now *after* `v` in the queue, so `v` will be visited before them despite having a distance greater than 4 - another contradiction.

So at all times, there is some distance `d` such that the queue contains only nodes at distance `d` or distance `d + 1`, and furthermore all nodes at distance `d` occur before any nodes at distance `d + 1` in the queue. This is a [loop invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant) of the BFS algorithm.

---

Suppose you are doing BFS on an M-by-N grid where every node is connected to all of its orthogonal neighbours. Then for any `d > 0`, the number of nodes at distance `d` from the start is at most `4*d`, so the maximum possible size of the queue is `4*d + 4*(d + 1)`. Also, the maximum distance between any two nodes is `M + N - 1`. Therefore, O(M + N) is an asymptotic bound on the size of the queue at any time.

In the case where some nodes from the grid are "missing" (i.e. the wrong colour for the region being flood-filled), the maximum distance is O(MN) rather than O(M + N); so this case is considerably more difficult. The intuition is that if the graph has longer paths then it has less "wide open" space for the paths to branch off in, resulting in a *smaller* queue. In the extreme case, the graph can be one long path, but in that case the queue's size is O(1).

However, there are some graphs where the `4*d` bound is breached and hence the queue can be larger. For example, it is possible to construct graphs in the form below where the graph size is O(2<sup>k</sup>) but the queue size reaches O(3<sup>k</sup>), so the space complexity of BFS is Θ((M + N)<sup>log<sub>2</sub> 3</sup>) on this family of graphs. So the quoted O(M + N) space complexity does not hold in the worst case, but probably holds in the average case.

[image]

This image was made by Heap Overflow (posted in the comments); the start node is in yellow, and the nodes in red will be in the queue simultaneously.

Comment: The `4*d` maximum is unclear and the `M + N - 1` is maximum is wrong. Are you thinking of an "empty" grid?

Comment: @HeapOverflow In graph theory a [grid](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_464.html) includes all orthogonal edges, and a [partial grid](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_440.html) is a subgraph of a grid. I guess it's likely that the OP is interested in flood-filling a partial grid (in that case the proof is more difficult), but this isn't explicit in the question.

Comment: Ok, they didn't state it well, but if you look at [the referenced LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/flood-fill/), you'll see it's indeed partial.

Comment: Alright, and I think it's worth editing to make it explicit, anyway.

Comment: Btw I don't know how to prove it and I'm quite interested :-)

Comment: Yes, it's quite interesting, and I may come back to write a proof later. The best I can do right now is wave my hands, I'm afraid!

Comment: The `4*d` bound actually *doesn't* apply. See this example, where I have 36 red cells at distance 7 from the yellow cell: https://ibb.co/Fg5Pc4c (consider the white cells non-visible).

Comment: How do you get (N+M)^1.5? Next larger version, 108 reds at distance 15: https://ibb.co/7z7KT7V

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207852/discussion-between-kaya3-and-heap-overflow).

Comment: @KellyBundy, it's still not clear what the space complexity is, but this image of yours clearly shows that `O(m+n)` does not cover the worst-case scenario. Does anyone know if there's any research on what the actual limit is?

Comment: I found a similar question on Stack Overflow proving that the space complexity is much higher than O(m+n). https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912382/1980246