# Space complexity of "Number of islands" BFS solution on Leetcode

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, space-complexity

For the Leetcode question "[Number of islands](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/)," I am trying to determine the SPACE complexity for the Breadth First Search solution.

```
from collections import deque


class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        num_islands = 0
        num_row, num_col = len(grid), len(grid[0])
        for r in range(num_row):
            for c in range(num_col):
                if grid[r][c] == '1':
                    num_islands += 1
                    self.bfs(r, c, grid)
        return num_islands
                
    def bfs(
        self, 
        row: int, 
        col: int, 
        grid: List[List[str]]
    ) -> None:
        queue = deque([(row, col)])
        while queue:
            r, c = queue.popleft()
            if grid[r][c] != '1':
                continue
            grid[r][c] = 'X'
            if r+1 <= len(grid)-1 and grid[r+1][c] == '1':
                queue.append((r+1, c))
            if r-1 >= 0 and grid[r-1][c] == '1':
                queue.append((r-1, c))
            if c+1 <= len(grid[0])-1 and grid[r][c+1] == '1':
                queue.append((r, c+1))
            if c-1 >= 0 and grid[r][c-1] == '1':
                queue.append((r, c-1))
```

I am looking at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912382/10095582), but that example doesn't really elaborate on how exactly worst case BFS space complexity = O(M · N), where M = # of rows and N = number of columns.  It states that the queue will have all of the leaf nodes, but how will that be?  Also, how are all of the leaf nodes proportional to M · N?  I think that diagram makes it hard to conceptualize.

I worked out a few examples, and I definitely see some cases where BFS space complexity > O(Max(M, N)), but can't grasp how it can be O(M·N) worst case.  Can someone please explain, preferably with a visual walkthrough?

Example with space complexity = O(Min(M, N)) if you start at top-left corner, but > O(Max(M, N)) if you start in the middle:

```
[
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

A visual example like the one above will be easier to digest.

Comment: You have O(MN) space for the grid, for bfs the extra space you need is just for the queue. How much could the queue be in worst case? O(V) where V is the number of the nodes, here V = MN. Thus in worst case it is: O(MN)+O(MN) = O(MN) total space complexity.

Comment: @coder The queue will never get to O(MN) because you are always popping from the left of the queue before adding more values, so not sure what you mean here.  Also, what is O(MN)+O(MN) = O(MN) supposed to represent?

Comment: I know that the queue will never reach MN space. However, you still need space O(MN) for your grid and thus my point is that even if your queue grows in the order of O(MN) you need overall space: O(MN) for the grid + O(MN) for the bfs queue, so overall worst case is O(MN)

Answer (score 2):

It's not so easy to arrange, but the worst case BFS queue size for an MxM matrix is indeed in Ω(M<sup>2</sup>)

Lets say we have an MxM block, with M odd, where a BFS starting in the center of one side can reach W cells at the same time, implying a queue size of W.

It's not hard to arrange these into a 2M+3 x 2M+3 block that starts in the center of one side and reaches 4W cells at the same time, like this:

```
###   ###
###   ###
#S#   #S#
 #     #
 #######
 #  #  #
#S# # #S#
### # ###
### S ###
```

We can then repeat the procedure with these new blocks, and then repeat again, etc., as long as we like.

As these blocks get bigger and bigger, the extra 3 rows and columns take up a smaller and smaller proportion of the total.  In terms of the number of repetitions of this procedure n, the length of the side M is in O(2<sup>n</sup>),

The maximum BFS queue size, of course is in Ω(4<sup>n</sup>), which is Ω(M<sup>2</sup>).

Here's what it looks like if you repeat the procedure a bunch of times.  A BFS starting at the top will find all the other end points at the same level:

[image]

Comment: Very clever - I’ll have to remember this one.